# Executing Ruby Script on ENTIRE Directory

Tags: ruby, parsing, directory

I'm currently writing a ruby script that takes a filename as it's input, parses out the text of that file, and generates an HTML file based on that file. I have the generation part working if I explicitly define a filename in the script, but is there anyway to build a loop in ruby to execute the script on all files ending with .txt in the current directory?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [glob](http://apidock.com/ruby/Dir/glob/class)

Example:

```
Dir.glob('*.txt').each do|f|
  puts f
end
```